# Phonegap contact form not working over PHP

Tags: php, html, cordova, contact-form

I´m having a very odd problem

I´m building a mobile app in HTML5 using phonegap to compile it to a native app.

Inside that app is a contact form and I can´t get it to work. I tried everything i could think of. But every-time i submit the form i receive the code of the php part on my screen.
Obviously the app works just fine on the browser, but not on my iphone.

I even tried using an iframe and added the form there, with the same results.

So my question is. How do i add a contact form (needs to send user info to the client email) inside my app

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your structure should be like this if doing holistic approach (html5 to native via Titanium/Phonegap)

```
/projects/apps/html5app/index.html
/projects/apps/html5app/contact.html

/projects/apps/html5app/assets/js/phonegap.js
/projects/apps/html5app/assets/js/jquery.js

/projects/apps/html5app/assets/css/css.css

/projects/apps/html5app/assets/images/logo.jpg
/projects/apps/html5app/assets/images/button.jpg
```

in contact.html you need to point to a live server with the PHP file

```
<form action="https://service.cdn-app.com/contact-form.php" method="get">
```

And then use a postback to submit a thanks page in AJAX or JSON so the user is not prompted to leave the app.

**Alternatively** UPDATE - Easier approach is just do button like this

```
<input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="submit contact"/>
```

Then on your jQuery you can do the action their (they won't leave your app and you can trigger a replace div with thanks etc)

// Start the jQuery form process engine

## jQUERY Sample

```
$.post('https://service.cdn-app.com/contact-form.php', {

    // These are the names of the form values

    FirstName: $('#FirstName_input').val(),
    LastName: $('#LastName_input').val(),
    Email: $('#Email_input').val(),
    MessageText: $('#MessageText_input').val()

    // HTML function

    }, function (html) {
        // Place the HTML in a astring
        var response=html;

        // PHP was done and email sent
        if (response=="success") {
            alert("Message sent!"); 
        } else {

            // Error postback
            alert("Sorry please fill all fields!"); 
        return false;
    }
});
```

## PHP SAMPLE

```
<?php

    // VARS
    $FirstName=$_GET["FirstName"];
    $LastName=$_GET["LastName"];
    $Email=$_GET["Email"];
    $MessageText=$_GET["MessageText"];
    $Headers = "From:" . $Email;

    //VALIDATION
    if(
    $FirstName=="" ||
    $LastName=="" ||
    $Email=="" ||
    $MessageText==""
    ) {
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        mail("youradmin@cdn.com","mobile app message",$MessageText, $Headers);
        echo "Success";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your welcome. The jQuery postback is the best solution - makes them stay within the app and creates a good UI and UX feel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

I do have a few more questions.
1. where can i get the phonegap.js
2. Can i simply copy/paste the jquery sample to my jquery.js
3. The link to my PHP should be $.post('http://xxxx.com/contact-form.php', { and <form action="https://xxxx.com/contact-form.php" method="get">
Or would i need to create 2 PHP files submit-action.php and contact-form.php
4. Is it necessary to follow the structure as you describe them above or can i use a different folder structure

Sorry for those dump questions, but i´m a bit overwhelmed here

Comment: 1 - Phonegap.js is generated via the IDE software you're using unless your using manual. 2 - Copy and paste the jQuery 3 - link to PHP should be the same, sorry it was the way I wrote it - the just sample dummy data - needs to be same form! and finally 4 folder structure was a suggestion and also to give you a clear view.. sometimes seeing folder structure like that helps..

Comment: OK, I did it exactly as you said, i copy/paste the jquery part to the bottom of my jquery.js and now everytime a page opens i receive a alert windo saying that i need to fill in all fields, as an additional problem i can submit the form using the browser, but when i compie it to ipa (using dreamweaver cs6 with phonegap) then the submit button does nothing.

Comment: Please update your question with your work full working code and files. I cannot see or help you further on that.

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you, but i got hit with a very nasty flue. Here the link to the mobile form. http://mobile.alicante-intermedia.com/contact.html  I created a jquery_form.js which only loads on the contact form. Every time i tried it, i´ll get this popup before i be able to fill in the fields

Comment: as a sidenote. I just tried the app using phonegap and the ipa works just fine. Only issue i´m having right now is this alert screen