# Using php form inside phonegap

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cordova

I have [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597891/phonegap-contact-form-not-working-over-php) for help to get my php form working inside an phonegap ipa. I did exactly as I was told and everything works just fine, even inside the ipa. Only problem I have is that I get this alert right at the moment when the page loads, obviously it should show up when client forgets to fill in a required field.

Here is what I did:

FORM in contact.html

```
 <form action="http://mobile.alicante-intermedia.com/submit_contact.php" method="get">
          <div class="form-element">
        <label for="txtfullname">Firstname</label>
        <input id="txtfullname" name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="required" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="txtemail">Lastname</label>
        <input id="txtemail" name="LastName" type="text" placeholder="required" required  />
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="txtcontact">Email</label>
        <input id="txtcontact" name="Email" type="email" placeholder="optional" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-element">
        <label for="txtmessage">Message</label>
        <textarea id="txtmessage" name="MessageText" placeholder="required" rows="5" required ></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="button" onclick="submit()" value="submit contact"/>
      </form>
```

Then I created a jquery_form.js file which loads only inside the conatct.html

```
$.post('http://mobile.alicante-intermedia.com/submit_contact.php', {

    // These are the names of the form values

    FirstName: $('#FirstName_input').val(),
    LastName: $('#LastName_input').val(),
    Email: $('#Email_input').val(),
    MessageText: $('#MessageText_input').val()

    // HTML function

    }, function (html) {
        // Place the HTML in a astring
        var response=html;

        // PHP was done and email sent
        if (response=="success") {
            alert("Message sent!"); 
        } else {

            // Error postback
            alert("Please fill all fields!"); 
        return false;
    }
});
```

And the php looks like this:

```
<?php

    // VARS
    $FirstName=$_GET["FirstName"];
    $LastName=$_GET["LastName"];
    $Email=$_GET["Email"];
    $MessageText=$_GET["MessageText"];
    $Headers = "From:" . $Email;

    //VALIDATION
    if(
    $FirstName=="" ||
    $LastName=="" ||
    $Email=="" ||
    $MessageText==""
    ) {
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        mail("myemail@email.com","mobile app message",$MessageText, $Headers);
        echo "Success";
    }
?>
```

Everything works fine except the alert screen. Anyone here who has an idea what went wrong?

Comment: Well your JavaScript code looks like it just immediately posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JavaScript code is "bare", not wrapped in any function or attached to any event handler, and therefore executes as soon as it is loaded - so it immediately posts an empty form when the jQuery script is first parsed.

Place it into the `onclick` event handler for the submit button:

```
// When the document has loaded...
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Bind this action as a function to be executed when the button is clicked...
  $('input[type="button"][value="submit contact"]').click(function() {
    $.post('http://mobile.alicante-intermedia.com/submit_contact.php', {

      // These are the names of the form values
      // EDIT: You have the wrong ids on these...

      FirstName: $('#txtfullname').val(),
      LastName: $('#txtemail').val(),
      Email: $('#txtcontact').val(),
      MessageText: $('#txtmessage').val()

      // HTML function

      }, function (html) {
          // Place the HTML in a astring
          var response=html;

          // PHP was done and email sent
          if (response=="success") {
            alert("Message sent!"); 
          } else {

            // Error postback
            alert("Please fill all fields!"); 
            return false;
          }
    });
  });
});
```

Since it is bound in the JavaScript code, remove the `onclick` from the button in your markup:

```
<input type="button" value="submit contact"/>
```

#### Edit:

The PHP you have is looking for values in `$_GET`, but you have posted them from jQuery. Look instead in `$_POST`.

```
$FirstName=$_POST["FirstName"];
$LastName=$_POST["LastName"];
$Email=$_POST["Email"];
$MessageText=$_POST["MessageText"];
```

Comment: Dreamweaver tells me that there is a syntax error at the end of the script. I tried it, but it´s not doing anything

Comment: Appears to have been an unclosed `}` after the `alert()`

Comment: ok, that did the trick, but now when i click on the button, nothing happens. have a look at http://mobile.alicante-intermedia.com/contact.html

Comment: Ah, because the button is `<input type='button'>` rather than `<button>` as my JS expects.  Change the selector to `$('input[type="button"][value="submit contact"]')`

Comment: ok, i changed the js to `// When the document has loaded...
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Bind this action as a function to be executed when the button is clicked...
  $('input[type="button"][value="submit contact"]').click(function().......` but it´s not working. Now i receive the alert that i need to fill in all fields, which i obviously did

Comment: Your PHP code is looking in `$_GET` but you have posted.  Get those values from `$_POST` in PHP. Debug with `var_dump($_POST);` in PHP.

Comment: @AlicaIM I added the necessary PHP above.

Comment: Michael, i changed the 4 rows to POSt (inside submit_contact.php) but it´s still pulling up the alert that i have to fill in all fields. I´m sorry for such a pain. but i´m doing the best i can to get this solved. Any idea whats still wrong here?

Comment: question would i have to use `<form action="http://mobile.alicante-intermedia.com/submit_contact.php" method="get">` or `<form action="http://mobile.alicante-intermedia.com/submit_contact.php" method="post">` ???  im still using method=¨get¨

Comment: hmm, i tried post and get and always this alert comes up, loosing my last hairs here

Comment: The form method doesn't actually matter, because you are not submitting the form tag. Instead, jQuery retrieves the values and sends them itself. You could also try in place of the form values in the `$.post()` call, you could do `$('form')[0].serialize()`

Comment: You need to _first_ get your PHP working or verify it is working by creating a simple HTML form using all the same inputs, and posting to it without jQuery.If that returns Success, you can proceed to get the `$.post()` call working.

Comment: I note also that you are making Email optional in the form, but PHP is requiring it...

Comment: Oh, and one more thing, possibly _the_ thing!  You PHP is echoing `Success`, but your jQuery is looking for `success`. See the difference?

Comment: And yet another - your input element ids are _not_ what you have in your jQuery code.  Have a look at what I changed above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and help. Everything is working now. I screwed up with the ids, after cleaning up everything i received the alert: Message Sent :)