# Contact form using php inside phonegap gives success alert but cant find mail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email, cordova

basically the question is [mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711074/using-php-form-inside-phonegap) of previous one in stack overflow. This form works but after a success alert, I don't find mail sent to a designated email id.

after i click the send button if i get success alert that means mail has been sent successfully, but when i check name@example.com (dummy) i should see mail in inbox but cant find one. What may be the problem. Am i doing wrong?

**contact.html**

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="css/theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // When the document has loaded...
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Bind this action as a function to be executed when the button is clicked...
      $('input[type="button"][value="send"]').click(function() {
        $.post('http://www.techmagzine.com/contact_us.php', {

          // These are the names of the form values
          // EDIT: You have the wrong ids on these...

          FirstName: $('#txtfullname').val(),
          LastName: $('#txtemail').val(),
          Email: $('#txtcontact').val(),
          MessageText: $('#txtmessage').val()

          // HTML function

          }, function (html) {
              // Place the HTML in a astring
              var response=html;

              // PHP was done and email sent
              if (response=="success") {
                alert("Message sent!"); 
                clear();
              } else {

                // Error postback
                alert("Please fill all fields!"); 
                return false;
              }
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="front" data-theme="b">
      <div class="header" id="header" data-role="header">
       <h3>Contact-Us</h3>
      </div>

      <div data-role="content">

            <label for="txtfullname">Firstname</label>
            <input id="txtfullname" name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="required" required />

            <label for="txtemail">Lastname</label>
            <input id="txtemail" name="LastName" type="text" placeholder="required" required  />

            <label for="txtcontact">Email</label>
            <input id="txtcontact" name="Email" type="email" placeholder="required" required />

            <label for="txtmessage">Message</label>
            <textarea id="txtmessage" name="MessageText" placeholder="required" rows="10" required ></textarea>

          <input type="button" value="send"/>



      </div>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

contact_us.php

```
<?php

    // VARS
    $FirstName=$_POST["FirstName"];
    $LastName=$_POST["LastName"];
    $Email=$_POST["Email"];
    $MessageText=$_POST["MessageText"];
    $Headers = "From:" . $Email;

    //VALIDATION
    if(
    $FirstName=="" ||
    $LastName=="" ||
    $Email=="" ||
    $MessageText==""
    ) {
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        mail("name@example.com","mobile app message",$MessageText, $Headers);
        echo "success";
    }
?>
```

Comment: is there a configured SMTP-Server (can you send mails?)
Did you try it with several mails?

Comment: @92_egdeH hi now i tried with SMTP configured mail address it worked i could find email but when i try with gmail and yahoo mail seems its not working..

Comment: At gmail look into "spam" folder (it's hidden in gmail webinterface in the left menu).
Yahoo - no idea.

I dont exatly know when google mark your mails as spam but it might have something to do with reverse-dns.

Good luck!

Comment: @92_egdeH looked in spam folder nothing there :-(

Comment: @92_egdeH looked in spam folder nothing there :-(