# Basic POST with JQuery Mobile from form using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile, forms, http-post

Firstly I apologize for posting another one of these questions, but I've dove through a ton of SO questions related to this topic and haven't be able to figure out my problem. I'm new to PHP and an amature at best using Jquery mobile and the like.

I'm attempting to post to a .php file and get a response back. Eventually this will evolve into a database posting yada yada. For now, I can't seem to get my response back from my post. I'm running Xampp to host the php, Jquery Mobile is being used in other functions so it does work properly,

HTML:

```
<form>
        <p>Username: </p><input type="text" id="username" value="" />
        <p>Password: </p><input type="text" id="password" value="" />
        <input type="button" onclick="submitLogIn()" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitLogIn() {

    alert("Submitting: " + $('#username').val() + $('#password').val());
    var dbURL = "http://localhost/testerpage.php";

    $.post(dbURL, {
        //These are the names of the form values
        Username: $('#username').val(),
        Password: $('#password').val()

    }, function (data,status) {
        alert(status); //Won't fire
        alert(html); //Won't fire
        var response = html;
        alert(response); //Won't fire
        if (response == "Success")
        {
            alert("Success!"); //Won't fire
            //testlog.innerHTML = "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Failure!");//Won't fire
            //testlog.innerHTML = "Failure";
        }

    });

    alert("Finished"); //Fires

};
```

PHP

```
<?php

    // VARS
    $Username=$_GET["Username"]; //Also tried _POST
    $Password=$_GET["Password"]; //Also tried _POST

    //VALIDATION
    if(
    $Username=="" ||
    $Password==""
    ) {
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        echo "Success";
    }
?>
```

My best guess is that something is wrong with the .php because all of the questions I've looked at seem to confirm my JavaScript is right. All of my alerts fire except the ones in the call back function. The username and password are also correctly being set so that isn't the problem. I tried using _POST and _GET in my .php, I originally was using _POST because I was posting data but I was following this question: ([Phonegap contact form not working over PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597891/phonegap-contact-form-not-working-over-php?rq=1)) and it did the opposite so I changed it. No difference. My .php is actually hosted for sure (I can navigate to it without an error). I also tried using the $.ajax function but had the same issues.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Added more of the HTML (all that should be relevant) per request, can't add it all as it is too long.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
            <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
            <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
            <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

            <!-- Stylesheets -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/snctfy2/snctfy2.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/snctfy2/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
            <link href="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <!-- Add .structure after theme-->

            <!-- Jquery core -->
            <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <!-- Jquery mobile library file -->
            <script src="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <!-- DateBox -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jqm-datebox.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datebox/jqm-datebox.core.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datebox/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datebox/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datebox/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script>


            <!-- Scripts (pre-load)-->
            <script src="js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <!-- CSS Override -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/override.css" />

            <title>SNCTFY</title>
        </head>
        <body>

    <!--there is some more <div> tags here unrelated-->
        <!--------------------------------------------------------Login Page---------------------

-------------------------------------------->
            <div data-role="page" id="login" data-theme="a" class="bPage">
                <div data-role="content">
                    <form>
                        <p>Username: </p><input type="text" id="username" value="" />
                        <p>Password: </p><input type="text" id="password" value="" />
                        <input type="button" onclick="submitLogIn()" value="Log In" />
                    </form>
                    <a href="#register" data-role="button">Register</a>
                    <button onclick="showAlert()">Test</button>
                    <p id="testlog">Results</p>
                </div>
            </div>

    <!-- more <div> pages -->

            <!-- Scripts (post-load)-->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                app.initialize();
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**EDIT2:** Changed JavaScript to one of the answers to test

```
function submitLogIn() {
    alert("Submitting: " + $('#username').val() + $('#password').val());
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/testerpage.php", 
        data: { "Username": username, "Password": password },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {

                alert(data);
            }
            else {
                alert('Successfully not posted.');
            }
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: why you are not using jquery ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try jquery Ajax

```
<body>
<form>
    <p>Username: </p><input type="text" id="username" value="" />
    <p>Password: </p><input type="text" id="password" value="" />
    <input type="button" onclick="submitLogIn()" value="Log In" />
</form>
<script>
function submitLogIn() {
alert("Submitting: " + $('#username').val() + $('#password').val());
var username =$('#username').val();
var password =  $('#password').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/testerpage.php",
    data:{"Username":username,"Password":password},
    success: function(data) {
    if (data) {

       alert(data);
    }
    else {
        alert('Successfully not posted.');
    }
    }
    });

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in PHP

```
<?php
$Username=$_POST["Username"]; //Also tried _POST
$Password=$_POST["Password"]; //Also tried _POST

//VALIDATION
if(
$Username=="" ||
$Password==""
) {
    echo "Error";
} else {
    echo "Success";
}
?>
```

Comment: @Draze try this and let me know.it's working or not ?

Comment: Nope not working, even tried making it within <script> tags in the html doc like you did (previously was external) and I'm not getting anything.

Comment: @ Draze Did you included jquery?

Comment: Yes it's included and working in other functions. I'm not sure what error I'm getting. I ran it through firebug and it ran through everything in the .ajax (in your version) but when it got to the success function it's like it skipped over it. I don't have an error being thrown anywhere though.

Comment: @Draze can you show me your full html amd php code?

Comment: That is the entire php code (Do I need more?) I'm editing the question with fuller HTML, though my current html file is ~700 lines (phonegap app using local navigation) so I'll just add the relevant parts.

Comment: @Draze hey is it possible for you to add your full jquery code in same html file?

Comment: @Draze becoz i used your code and its perfectly work for me on i add javascript code to html file and add jquery <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Good to know that the code works. Must be something with the <script> tag order in the html files. Like I said, I have a function using $.get fine in the same .js file. I tried adding just that function within the html file and it didn't work either. I'll mess around with it some more tomorrow and see if I can find the root cause.

Comment: @Draze upvote if anything is helping you with our conversation :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function submitLogIn() {

    alert("Submitting: " + $('#username').val() + $('#password').val());
    var dbURL = "http://localhost/testerpage.php";

    //These are the names of the form values
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    $.ajax({
         url: dbURL,
         type:'post',
         data:'&username='+username+'&pass='+password,
         success:function(response){
              alert(response);
         }
     });

};




<?php

    // VARS
    $Username=$_POST["username"]; //Also tried _POST
    $Password=$_POST["pass"]; //Also tried _POST

    //VALIDATION
    if(
    $Username=="" ||
    $Password==""
    ) {
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        echo "Success";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code
script

```
<script>
function submitLogIn() {
  alert("Submitting: " + $('#username').val() + $('#password').val());
  var dbURL = "http://localhost/testerpage.php";

  $.post(dbURL, {
    //These are the names of the form values
    Username: $('#username').val(),
    Password: $('#password').val()

}, function (data,status) {
    if (data == "Success")
    {
        alert("Success!"); //Won't fire
        //testlog.innerHTML = "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Failure!");//Won't fire
        //testlog.innerHTML = "Failure";
    }

});   
alert("Finished"); //Fires
};
</script>
```

PHP

```
// VARS
$Username=$_POST["Username"]; //Also tried _POST
$Password=$_POST["Password"]; //Also tried _POST

//VALIDATION
if(
$Username=="" ||
$Password==""
) {
    echo "Error";
} else {
    echo "Success";
}
```

Comment: This did not resolve the issue, as the only thing that changed was the callback function which isn't being called at all currently.

Comment: Draze, i changed the callback as well as the $_post in the php code. Please check if your dburl works. Do you have any errors in the developer console ?. Do you know how to debug your javascript code?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond. I've actually tried to do a simpler post and it is not working either. If I do an .ajax response I get the error function thrown, but the only thing that gets thrown is the 'error' status. The error message is null. I'm thinking that something is wrong with access to my localhost php script, I don't know about permissions or what needs changed, but it's the only thing I can think of that would be wrong.